# At what point is the check for whether or not I meet the criteria for Ending C?

Tags: nier-replicant-1.22474487139

This may be a bit spoilery, so please read at your own caution.

---

I played *NieR: Gestalt* back in the day so I’ve done this before, but it’s been a while.

The criteria for route C is that I need

> to have obtained all of the weapons, that means all 33 weapons, including those from the Recycled World quest (a DLC in the original game, but included in version 1.22474487139), which would show 100% completion in the weapons page. This does  **NOT** include the free *NieR: Automata* DLC weapons (Virtuous Treaty/Contract/Dignity, and Cruel Oath).

Route C is different from the previous route (B) in that

> you are presented a choice after the point where route B cuts off— assuming you meet the aforementioned criteria.

However, my dumb self

> missed the **ONE** weapon in the Shadowlord’s castle; entering said castle is the point of no return for the ending.

---

My question is simple: is the check for whether I will be given the choice for route C resolved prior to said point of no return, or is it as long as I meet the criteria by the time the choice is presented to me? That is, is my negligence going to cause me to end with route B for a *second* time or will I be able to meet the criteria past this point of no return and still get the third ending?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay. I went ahead

> and passed the point of no return, grabbed the  Phoenix Sword,

and completed route C. Therefore, I can confirm that you can complete route C without meeting the route C choice criteria prior to the point of no return!

Good news for anyone who accidentally ended up in the same position as me :)